# Unexpected token }. Celcius to Farenheit convertor

Tags: javascript

I just wanna say one thing before I get to the question. I am a young guy who takes interest in programming, so please don't rage at me if the answer is super easy. PS. Sorry for my bad English :P

Here's the thing. I'm trying to make this converter between Fahrenheit and Celsius in JavaScript. I simply cant get what I`enter code here`'m doing wrong. My code;

```
//Line 2 asks the user what he/she want to convert. Either celcius to farenheit, or farenheit to celcius
var userChoice = prompt("For converting farenheit to celcius, type FtoC. For converting celcius to farenheit, type CtoF");


//Defines a function to calculate the math
var celciustofarenheit = function (userChoice) {
    if (userChoice === "CtoF")
        var CtoFchoice = prompt("Whats the degree you want to convert?")
            var result1 = CtoFchoice * 9 / 5 + 32;
                console.log(CtoFchoice, "is", result1, "in farenheit!")
}
    if (userChoice === "FtoC") {
        var FtoCchoice = prompt("Whats the number you want to convert?")
            var result2 = FtoCchoice - 32 * 5 / 9;
                console.log(FtoCchoice, "is", result2, "in celcius!")
    }
};
```

Please say to me what I'm doing wrong, rather than just paste the correct code! :)

Comment: Structure your code more carefully and you'll instantly see what's wrong.

Comment: use http://www.jslint.com/ : the will help you in js !

Comment: Don't apologize for being new.  Everyone is new, at least once.  Many of us are new all the time (constantly learning)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a curly brace after `if (userChoice === "CtoF")`. You'll spot errors like this directly if you just indent your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

Correct code

```
//Defines a function to calculate the math
var celciustofarenheit = function (userChoice) {
    if (userChoice === "CtoF") {
        var CtoFchoice = prompt("Whats the degree you want to convert?");
        var result1 = CtoFchoice * 9 / 5 + 32;
        console.log(CtoFchoice, "is", result1, "in farenheit!");
    }

    if (userChoice === "FtoC") {
        var FtoCchoice = prompt("Whats the number you want to convert?");
        var result2 = FtoCchoice - 32 * 5 / 9;
        console.log(FtoCchoice, "is", result2, "in celcius!");
    }
};
```